# Having trouble removing PHP extension

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

On my website I have been trying to remove the **PHP** extension's on every page; I am worried that I may interfere with the SEO and end up glitching the site.

I have tried alot of methods on the internet but none of them seem to be working ? Maybe I am doing something wrong, or it's an internal control panel error ?

**Code:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

**No results from this or any others, advice ?**

Comment: "but none of them seem to be working" what does that mean? What do you expect to happen, when you do what? And what does happen instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has always worked for me:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

In one project here we used:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Which you could try as well

Comment: Your second example is similar to the OP's try!

Comment: @Thamilan _very!_

Comment: First example, no need for `QSA`, because you don't change the query string. Second example, no need for `NC`, because the pattern does not contain any alphabetic characters. Beyond that, both look fine.